# An idea we form in our mind about a place

Tags: word-request

I wrote

> We all could have some .... of a place when we hear about it.

I look for a word which means the image or idea we have about a country that we got from various sources (TV, other people)

For example, we may think Japan is a green place full of cherry blooms with very polite people who usually eat sea foods!...

If I want to translate a Persian phrase I can say:

- imagination
- image
- mental background

Or I myself can make a word like *pre image* or *prior image*. However as I checked they aren't valid or idiomatic.

Comment: Have you tried using a dictionary or thesaurus? Which one? Most online dictionaries provide synonyms or links to synonyms. I have close-voted this question because you should look the word up in a dictionary or thesaurus and then list possible alternatives and what difficulty you had with them, for example, you're not sure they fit the context.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I wonder what is the usage of "word-request" tag, I explained my request as possible. I really had no idea what the word could be. Otherwise I didn't ask it. I even thought of the word *Pre-image* which certainly doesn't exist!

Comment: *Image* works. In fact, that is the word I thought of when I read your question title. Possibly  it's the best word. I am not sure why you don't like this word.

Comment: @Ahmad: You probably want ***preconception***, which more strongly alludes to this being the way you conceptualise something ***before*** you have any direct first-hand experience (and thus more strongly implies that what you *expect* to be the case will in fact turn out to be ***not accurate*** when you see the reality).

Answer (score 4):

You could use "conception" (perhaps verbally as conceive) or "[notion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/notion)"

Conception means "an idea formed in the mind". A notion suggests the conception is vague or imperfect.

> My conception of Japan is of crowded cities filled with office workers.
>
> My notions of Mars are based mostly on movies.
>
> She conceived Mexico to be a hot dry land.

See also this, [question about the difference between notion and conception](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15568/notion-and-conception) on English Stack Exchange.

We can also talk about the "mental image" that we have about a place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a phrase or word which describes thoughts *before* actually encountering or experiencing *something*

> preconceived notions
>   *We all could have* ***preconceived notions*** *of a place when we hear about it.*
>
> some ideas
>   *We all could have* ***some ideas*** *of a place when we hear about it.*
>
> some thoughts
>   *We all could have* ***some thoughts*** *of a place when we hear about it.*

all can imply less than a deep understanding of *something*.

Answer (score 1):

The idea you're describing is called a

*mental image*

From http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mental-image:

> *A mental picture of something not real or present that is produced by the memory or the imagination.* Example: "Viggo Mortensen doesn't fit my own mental image of Strider, but soon won me over all the same."

The example sentence shows the *pre* or *prior* aspect you are looking for.

Here is this term used in your Japan example:

> My mental image of Japan was a green place full of cherry blossoms with very polite people eating fish and seafood.  When I spent my sabbatical there last year, I found all that, but much more -- etc.